# Is there a way to filter shortcode attributes when the shortcode parameter hasn't been passed to shortcode_atts()?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

We're using a 3rd party plugin that has a shortcode (ie [SHORTCODEHERE]) for something and I need to dynamically modify the attributes passed to it however when the plugin calls renders their shortcode they use shortcode_atts without passing in the shortcode parameter so the filter shortcode_atts_SHORTCODEHERE never gets called.

Is there another way to modify the shortcode attributes dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can filter and modify any 3rd party plugin's shortcode attributes and change the shortcode output according the updated shortcodes

**Case Study**
For example we have an 3rd party plugin's shortcode **usermeta** and its required a attribute **user_id**
and we want to modify the **user_id** attribute value.

**The following solution is tested and working 100%.**

```
// hook the custom callback function on the do_shortcode_tag action hook 
add_filter( 'do_shortcode_tag', 'update_shortcode_attr_and_output', 1, 4 );


//callback function to filter and modify the usermeta shortcode attr & output
function update_shortcode_attr_and_output( $output, $tag, $attr, $m ) {

         //Filter the shortcode tag
        if (  'usermeta' == $tag && ! isset( $attr['user_id'] ) ) {

            // Update ShortCode Attribute user_id value
            $attr['user_id'] = $this->user_id;

            /**
             * update outup according updated attr
             * Refrence: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/shortcodes.php?rev=38713#L342
             */
            global $shortcode_tags;
            $content = isset( $m[5] ) ? $m[5] : null;
            $output  = $m[1] . call_user_func( $shortcode_tags[ $tag ], $attr, $content, $tag ) . $m[6];

        }

        return $output;
}
```

Comment: `do_shortcode_tag` is a filter not an action